# Битрикс. API. Копирование файла

Tags: битрикс

Мне нужно, зная id файла, скопировать его в туже папку, где выполняется текущий скрипт. Делаю так:

`CFile::CopyFile($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"], true, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$APPLICATION->GetCurDir())`

Но файл копируется в туже папку, где и лежит. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: папка текущего скрипта `__DIR__`, может так лучше будет

Comment: @apelsinka223, данный вариант `CFile::CopyFile($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"], true, __DIR__)` тоже не сработал

Comment: тогда указываейте строкой путь, должно сработать

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
copy($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].CFile::GetPath($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]), __DIR__."/images/".$arFields['ID']."/".$arFileDetail["FILE_NAME"]);
```